# Display multiple count values on joined tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a count of the userID's that exist in 2 tables,
I also have an inner join for the tables on the userID so that I can search for the count of one table,  based off the BadgeID from the other table.
So far it returns the user count for one table, but I can't seem to figure out how to return a count for userID on both tables, Any suggestions?

```
   SELECT DISTINCT live_event.usid, COUNT(1) AS membercount 
   FROM live_event
   INNER JOIN member_badges ON live_event.usid = member_badges.usid
   WHERE bdgid = 14
```

Comment: What database are you using? (I'm going to guess mysql simply because it'll run an aggregate query like this and return the wrong data instead of an error).  have you read the purpose of a group by statement?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I'm not sure what you really want.

Comment: Right now it return a count of the total usid for the live_event table, i would also like for it to display the total count of usid's for the member_badges table as well

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for; but based on what I could understand, are sub-queries perhaps the route you are wanting to go?

```
    select
        (select count(*) from firsttable where userid = {userid})
    as count1,
        (select count(*) from secondtable where userid = {userid})
    as count2
```

Where {userid} would be your bdgid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use union select to connect results from two tables

```
select useid, count(*) from (
select useid from firsttable
union select useid from second table ) group by useid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  COALESCE(MAX(
    CASE
      when tbl_name='live_event' then cnt_records
      else null
    END), 0) as cnt_live_event,
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE
        when tbl_name='member_badges' then cnt_records
        else null
      END), 0) as cnt_member_badges
FROM
(
  SELECT
    'live_event' AS tbl_name,
    usid as user_id,
    count(*) AS cnt_records
  FROM live_event
  GROUP BY 'live_event', usid
  UNION
  SELECT
    'member_badges',
    usid as user_id,
    count(*)
  FROM member_badges
  GROUP BY 'member_badges', usid
) grouped_counts
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```

The above query would get you the user counts even if the `usid` is present in only one of the tables.